# Determining Number of Outputs for trading type ANN

Tags: artificial-intelligence, output, neural-network

I am currently trying to implement an ANN that does 1 for 1 Trades with 8 different possible Goods.
I am wondering how I determine the number of outputs necessery for the ANN to perform adequatly.
Should the number of outputs be equivalent to the number of possible trades? Meaning if I have 8 different Goods and can trade each one for each of the 8 Goods does the ANN need 8*8 outputs?

To summarize does an ANN need a number of outputs equal to the number of distinct actions it can perform?

edit: To clarify the goods have worth specific to a situation which is the input given to the ANN. the 8*8 is referring to the number of possible combination of trades one of the goods for any other.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Classification engine

Neural networks (feed forward) are classification engines - they are not necessarily ment for "storing knowledge" such as [decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) and [logical knowledge bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic#Knowledge_representation).

Though it certainly *is* possible to store predefined decisions inside a neural network - much like a gigantic if-clause.

### Number of outputs

If the different outputs assigns different classes, you should use one outputs signal per classification instance.
If you were to decide to let one output signal imply different classes depending on the output value, you are hinting to the network that a output signal of `10` "is a better class" than one with output `-10`. Therefore I would strongly recommend to use one output signal per class, although this will require more training (at the advantage of possibly fewer plateaus in the search space).

---

#### I am not sure what you are refering to with:

> Meaning if I have 8 different Goods and can trade each one for each of
>   the 8 Goods does the ANN need 8^8 outputs

Are you going to input a set if "stock values" and force the net to output which stocks to buy and sell?

Comment: The trading is much simpler than that, I have Goods the partner has Goods and I try to determine what the best offered and requested Goods in 1 for 1 trade would be given a certain input. I have seen a NN used for Poker and the input was an integer representing a card. Does this only work for input?

Comment: Neural networks is no way to go for poker! Since there's always "a best way" to play your hand in poker - the preferred technique would be a Decision Tree or a Bayesian Tree with a Min-max implementation.

Comment: Are your input signals "the price of each separate goods"? If that is the case, you would be able to construct a tree to output specific signals to indicate which goods to trade

Comment: The goods themselves have no worth, they get their value based on the situation given as inputs. I have seen many Neural Poker Bots, seems like they have some success, but well i am not trying poker here. Just wondering why he could give one input with a Value representing a card type.

Comment: Oh, the 8^8, I mean 8*8 the number of possible combinations of trades one of the goods for any another. The tree you mentioned would be a basic if then else tree?

Comment: Yes, altough is the neural net is supposed to act according to the `maximized expectation criterion` net network would have to be trained on all 1025010 hands. Since there are only 52 different cards you may be handed, it is still reasonable to use one input signal per card. (Such that input i_1 to i_13 refers to hearts, i_14 to i_26 refers to spades, and so on)

Comment: You would require 8 outputs for your "trading partner"'s goods, and 8 outputs for your own goods - equalling 16 outputs.

Comment: Ok so it is possible using one output for multiple classes, just not recommended. So it would be some kind of trade-off between learning time and net accuracy?

Comment: Yes, as you add outputs to your net you will increase the time complexity of calculating all the weights. BUT using one output for multiple classes may create further plateaus in the search space. A neural network output should also be regarded as a "level of truth for a activation signal" (eg: -1 would be "nothing" and 1 would be "perfect")